# Compare time stamps in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I want to check if part of the content of the input box contains the current YYMMDD HH. I don't want to check MM and SS because this will be inaccurate taking into consideration the time passed to do the comparison. So, I did

```
  const dayjs = require('dayjs')
  companionPage.countNameInputBox().invoke('val').then((text) => {
   expect(text.trim()).to.have.text(dayjs().format('YYMMDD HH'))
  })
```

But I got:

[image]

How can I remove the comparison for MM and SS? and solve the above error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you will have always a fixed number (9) of characters in `230509 17`, you can use `.slice(0,9)`:

```
const dayjs = require('dayjs')
companionPage.countNameInputBox().invoke('val').then((text) => {
   expect(text.trim().slice(0,9)).to.have.text(dayjs().format('YYMMDD HH'))
})
```

```js
console.log('230509 174301'.slice(0,9))
```

Comment: yes, that worked. I just changed the function to expect(text.trim().slice(0,9)).contains(dayjs().format('YYMMDD HH'))